# tracking after cluster group status c++

Tags: c++, cluster-computing

I would like to write a cluster aware application that will track after the status of a cluster group.

to be more specific, I'd like to probe after the group's Owner. The application should know if the local machine is the owner of the group or not and behave accordingly.

can I probe the registry for that? if yes, where? if not, does someone know any win32 api calls that will provide this info?

many thanks,

ofer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the [Cluster API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369075.aspx). I'm not going to write up an entire walk-through, but using the API you can get all (or virtually all) of the information exposed by the OS tools, and then some.